# return multiple result sets from ms access to ado.net

Tags: database, ms-access, ado.net, dataset, data-access

hey guys i want to fetch 3 tables in 1 single ado.net call from my ms access database, however i get an error when i am trying to do that

when i change my sql query to just fetch 1 table, my code works fine

can anyone let me know how to achieve this with ms access? because i have been doing this with sql server since ages without any problems. perhaps access does not support multiple result sets? i have not worked much with access. please help. below is my code for reference:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DatabaseFile.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2; SELECT * FROM Table3;", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

**UPDATE: guys this does not look possible. so i had to write really stupid code to get what i wanted, complete waste of computing resources:**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Table1"));
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Table2"));
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Table3"));

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DatabaseFile.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1;", con);
da.Fill(ds, "Table1");

da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table2;";
da.Fill(ds, "Table2");

da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table3;";
da.Fill(ds, "Table3");
```

Comment: Can you either add the SQL you are trying to run, or edit your original post so we can see the rest of the lines?

Comment: @justin - sql statement is already up there with the question in the code block above (hardcoded in the data adapter constructor)

Comment: I tryed separating statements with GO but doesn't work either

Comment: yeah does not look possible - even google search suggests that. ITS A SHAME access does not support this basic feature :-(

Comment: It's pretty clear why Jet does not support such a feature, because there is no server-side process to serialize multiple SQL statements appropriately. Complaining about this is really a case of not understanding the basics about the tool you've chosen.

Comment: If switching databases is an option, why not use SQL Server free version and get more functionality than sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I know, if your data reside inside the Access mdb, you cannot have multiple data sets. If instead you use Access to connect to an external data source, you could use pass-through queries and do that, but I do not think this is your case. (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126992)

Comment: yeah looks like you are correct... i will wait for couple of hours to see if someone has a hack ;-) thanks for your help mate

Comment: @Raj: The Jet database engine does not support multiple commands in a single command text. I don't think there is a hack around this limitation. :-)

Comment: @tomalak - access really sucks! i will have to move to sqlite ;-)

Comment: @Raj: Access really sucks at things it has not been made for. Virtually everything sucks at stuff it hasn't been made for. ;-)