# C# Alternative of Multiple Active Result Set for MS-Access

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to know if a multiple active result set, [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx), exists for the Microsoft's Access database? I am aware this exists for SQL Server. I tried using it with Access but it didn't work for me. I want to know how to use MARS with Access.

Comment: MS-Access (Jet) does not have a multiple result-set capability. You need to create separate result-sets for each query.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but should answer your question - [return multiple result sets from ms access to ado.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726263/return-multiple-result-sets-from-ms-access-to-ado-net)

Comment: I already saw that post. But really not helpful for me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, Microsoft Access does not support multiple active result sets (MARS). It is not supported by the ODBC provider and the reason why that is not the case should be obvious if you think about it in terms of what MARS actually offers you from a performance stand point.

If you think about the most important reason for MARS to exist is if you have stored procedures executed on a SQL server that produce multiple result sets. If you have such queries you need to be able to somehow access those multiple results sets.

But in Access there is no such thing as stored procedures. If you have multiple queries you can just execute each one of them separately and get the result set for each. Hence, no need for MARS.

**NOTE**

In light of the comments, here's an example of how to have two data readers open at the same time:

```
 using(var connection1 = new OdbcConnection("your connection string here"))
 {
   connection1.Open();
   using(var connection2 = new OdbcConnection("your connection string here"))
   {
     connection2.Open();

     using(var cmd1 = connection1.CreateCommand())
     {
       cmd1.CommandText = "YOU FIRST QUERY HERE";

       using(var dataReader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
       {
          while(dataReader1.Read())
          {
             // keep reading data from dataReader1 / connection 1
             //  .. at some point you may need to execute a second query

             using(var cmd2 = connection2.CreateCommand())
             {
                cmd2.CommandText = "YOUR SECOND QUERY HERE";

                // you can now execute the second query here
                using(var dataReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   while(dataReader2.Read())
                   {

                   }
                }
             }
          } 
       }
     }
     connection2.Close();
   }
   connection1.Close();
 }
```

Comment: So, is there any other alternative so that i can have different data reader open at once?

Comment: Yes, you can open multiple connections to the same database and execute multiple commands, each with it's own data reader..

Comment: what i really need is to open another data reader within a data reader....... But everytime i got an error saying you have already a reader opened........

Comment: you can certainly have two data readers open at the same time. But you need to also open a new connection to use with the second data reader. You can't use the same connection for both data readers..

Comment: @user1929236 that's exactly what MARS allows - which MS Access doesn't support. You need to close the previous data reader before opening another, there is no way around this i'm afraid. Just a bit of advice, if you are looking for scalability **don't use MS Access**.

Comment: yes, that is what i am saying. In sql server we ca do this using MARS but not here. Is there a way in access so that i can do it here also?

Comment: @user1929236 Did you read my last comment? "*You need to close the previous data reader before opening another, there is no way around this i'm afraid*"....

Comment: sorry @james i just saw it now. Can you tell me to built the package of the software which database I should prefer? Because Sql Server requires a pre installed files..

Comment: @user1929236 - you should look at SQLite or Microsoft SQL Server Express edition. But see my updated answer above.