# Multiple readers access database

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbdatareader

I've read about an option in the connection string called MARS (MultipleActiveResultSets), but from what I've gathered it is only a valid argument for Sql Server 2005. Is there an equivalent setting for OleDB to open an access database with multiple readers?

I am aware that I can create multiple connections, one for each reader. I am currently doing this, but it would preferable to execute both readers on a single connection. Here's my current connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyDb.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyPassword"
```

Comment: MARS is not available for Access. You need two connection strings or close the reader before opening another one.

Comment: I thought that was the case. It won't be quite as pretty, but it works at least.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484102/c-sharp-alternative-of-multiple-active-result-set-for-ms-access)

Comment: @Niranjan I've been searching all over for this exact information. Thank you very much for the link.